# How can I access the Cell Array in my getCell method? (Java)

Tags: java, methods

my Task is to make an implementation of Conway's Game of Life. Therefor I need to create the class GameMap. In this class I will initialize an 2D Array.
Therefor I use those two methods.

```
private static Cell[][] buildCellArray(int width, int height){
        Cell[][] cellArray = new Cell[width][height];
        int i;
        int j;
        for(i = 0; i < width; i++) {
            for(j = 0; j < height; j++) {
                cellArray[i][j] = new Cell();
            }
        }
        return cellArray;
    }
    
    public GameMap(int sizeX, int sizeY) {
        buildCellArray(sizeX, sizeY);
    }
```

Now I want to access the cellArray to access a special Cell with the getCell(int posX, int posY) method.
My question is how I can access the cellArray?
I wanted to access it like this:

```
public Cell getCell(int posX, int posY){
        return cellArray[posX][posY];
    }
```

So that I get the Cell at a special position.
I hope somebody can help me out.

So the complete code part is:

```
public class GameMap {
    private static Cell[][] buildCellArray(int width, int height){
        Cell[][] cellArray = new Cell[width][height];
        int i;
        int j;
        for(i = 0; i < width; i++) {
            for(j = 0; j < height; j++) {
                cellArray[i][j] = new Cell();
            }
        }
        return cellArray;
    }
    
    public GameMap(int sizeX, int sizeY) {
        buildCellArray(sizeX, sizeY);
    }
    
    
    public Cell getCell(int posX, int posY){
        return cellArray[posX][posY];
    }
}
```

And the IDE says that cellArray in the method getCell is not a variable.

Comment: What is the problem with the code you provided? What doesn't work? Do you need to pass cellArray as an argument to getCell or make cellArray a class-level variable?

Comment: The problem is that the IDE says cellArray cannot be resolve to a variable.

Comment: `cellArray` is a local variable in a method and **therefore** does not exist outside of that method. Hence you can't access it from another method. Perhaps if you [edit] your question and post a [mcve] that shows what you are trying to do, I may be able to suggest a solution. For now, and based on the current details in your question, I suggest making `cellArray` a member of the class containing method `buildCellArray()`.

Comment: I edited it so maybe it helps you to find my mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IDE says `cellArray` cannot be resolve to a variable because it is local variable, to pass this problem just move `Cell[][] cellArray = new Cell[width][height];` outside the `buildCellArray()`.

```
public class GameMap {

    Cell[][] cellArray;

    private static Cell[][] buildCellArray(int width, int height){
        int i;
        int j;

        for(i = 0; i < width; i++) {
            for(j = 0; j < height; j++) {
                cellArray[i][j] = new Cell();
            }
        }
    
        return cellArray;
    }
    
    public GameMap(int sizeX, int sizeY) {
         buildCellArray(sizeX, sizeY);
    }

    public Cell getCell(int posX, int posY){
        return cellArray[posX][posY];
    }
}
```

Comment: Using global variables should generally be avoided

Comment: @Malone2409 I made some other changes.

Comment: @Nima In this case he needs it.

Comment: It did NOT work, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63095257/how-to-avoid-java-lang-nullpointerexception-in-my-code?noredirect=1&lq=1